# Conjugated-Phase Matching

Tags: optics, imaging, hologram, radar

I am working on imaging applications of phase-conjugation in optics, in particular phase-conjugation imaging from recorded holograms.  I have found several useful sources, but I cannot find a book that allows me to familiarize with the derivations from scratch. I would like to find a book where I can follow the derivation from a recorded hologram to the construction of an image by phase conjugation so as to estimate cross-resolution, depth-degradation, etc. Do you know a book (on optics, radars, math-physics) where I can find such an expostion? Thanks in advance.